# Area of parallelogram from a linear operator

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

let $L: \mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R^2$ be a linear operator which is invertible. Let 
{$u, v$} be a linearly independent set in $\mathbb R^2$. Find a formula for the area of the parallelogram induced by $L(u)$ and $L(v)$ in terms of the area of the parallelogram induced by $u$ and $v$.

So I'm trying to find det($L(u)$,$L(v)$) since this is the area. Not sure on how to do this problem.

Comment: Hint: $\det(AB)=\det(A)\det(B)$

Comment: Apply it with $A=L$ and $B=(u,v)$.