# inventing a linear operator that doubles the area of a parallelogram

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, area

I have the exact same question as [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1213549/area-of-parallelogram-from-a-linear-operator/1711776#1711776), but wanted to ask, how can we invent a linear operator $L: R^2 -> R^2$ that doubles the area of a parallelogram

---

ETA:

will the matrix $\pmatrix{4 & 1 \\ 6 & 2}$ work?

Comment: Just find a $2\times 2$ matrix with determinant $\pm 2$.

Comment: Thanks. I edited the question above, hoping that matrix works.

Comment: Test it out and see what happens.